# Determining whether gem was called as Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, rake-task

I'm writing a gem that includes some rake tasks. I have some code in the before_configuration method that I want to run when my gem is loaded by the app at runtime, but NOT when a task is run with rake. How can I determine that?

**lib/mygem/tasks.rake:**

```
namespace :mygem do
  task :dosomething do   
    puts "DONE"
  end
end
```

**lib/mygem/railtie.rb:**

```
require "rails"
module Mygem
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    config.before_configuration do
      #is_rake_task = ?
      if !is_rake_task
        # Do something
      end  
    end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rake` is only defined in rake context.

So, you could simply go something like that :

```
if defined? Rake
   # rake specific stuff
else
   # non rake stuff
end
```

Edit :

While this will work perfectly with `rails s`, there's a problem with zeus on development environment : zeus will require rake.

If this is a problem, if think you can take advantage of [Rake.application](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/rake_module.rb#L9), which sets an instance variable when [a rake task is executed](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/bin/rake#L33).

I've tested this in a `zeus s` context :

```
> Rake.instance_variable_defined? :@application
false
```

And in a `rake <task>` context :

```
> Rake.instance_variable_defined? :@application
true
```

So, a complete solution would be :

```
if defined?( Rake ) and Rake.instance_variable_defined?( :@application )
   # rake specific stuff
else
   # non rake stuff
end
```

Comment: @OlivierElMekki- There's a problem with this, it turns out. When running your app in development from the console (`rails server`), Rake *is* defined, so there's no way to distinguish...

Comment: It's not the case in my current app (rails-4.0.0, tried both with plain `rails s` and `bundle exec rails s`). Don't you have any lib loading rake in your gem set ?

Comment: Ok, did some more test : I have no problem with `rails s`, neither with god launching unicorn, but I've indeed found a problem with `zeus s`. I suppose it's because of that "development_environment > prerake" line in `zeus start`. Are you using zeus ?

Comment: Ok, found a mean for zeus too. Interesting problem :) I'm not sure how we should feel about zeus loading rake in server process, though.

Comment: Hmm yea interesting- I dont have zeus, but could very well be another gem- ill try this with a clean install..

Comment: I suppose a gem requiring rake would be bogus, because I can't see any usefulness for that. So, except if gem has explicitly called `Rake.application`, the `:@application` trick should work too (and if this is meant to be distributed, better consider Rake could be there).